# Full passenger list for specific flight

Tags: web-services, passenger, sabre

Is there an web service that allows get the full passenger list for a flight (whitout filters), we need to generate a document to our principar airport and this includes passenger quantities.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, Welcome to Stack Overflow. SO is more for specific programming errors. I suggest you contact Sabre or the airlines directly. I may be mistaken, but I don't think its legal for an airline to give passenger information to any non government organization.

Comment: I need the list to generate a resume of quantities of passenger like childrens, adults, diplomatic, etc. not like personal info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There won't be any way to do this type of data retrieval using Sabre unless you are working with the travel management company that booked all of the passengers. You'll be better off asking the airlines for that information directly, but I highly doubt that will work, either. Sorry...

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of services in HP shares to get the complete passenger list for a flight. that contains PNR & passenger names. those web services can accessible to only airlines.

Comment: How is this a solution to the question?  You're merely confirming the existence of a solution.

Answer (score 0):

The sabre service is called ACS_PassengerListRQ.